# Windows 2008 R2 Server Core Disk Space Requirements/Recomendations

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esx, disk-space-utilization, windows-server-core

I'm in the preparation stage to roll out a few Windows 2008 R2 Server Core in my VMware ESX environment.

In looking over the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753802(WS.10).aspx) it looks like Server Core can operate in a little as 6.5 GB of hard drive space.

> **Less disk space required.** A Server Core installation requires only about 3.5 gigabytes (GB) of disk space to install and approximately 3 GB for operations after the installation.

I am curious as to anyone’s real world experience and recommendations with regard to this requirement. Is it realistic?

A little bit about our environment:

> Less than 25 users, and around 75
>   computers/servers in our current AD
>   system. These systems will be
>   responsible for normal AD operations
>   and print servers for 5 printers -
>   nothing to big here.

Answer (score 1):

The [base W2K8 installation Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755116(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_1) says that while it only needs 10GB to install but 40GB is recommended. That phrasing is significantly different to the Server Core document [*"3GB is required for operations"*]. I've never tried running Server Core for long with a tiny system volume but I can certainly say that running full blown Server 2008 for an extended period on less than around 40Gig plus enough space for a page file (unless it's on a different drive) is not a good idea.

Increasing the size of a W2K8 System drive is not difficult so you could take the risk but I wouldn't do that unless you know you will be able to increase the volume size relatively easily in future if the worst happens. The way I look at that I'd be strongly inclined to allocate the space now if space is tight. Is the 10-20GB that you're trying to save really worth it?

Answer (score 0):

Server core can use less disk space but you have to pay attention to [what roles you can install on server core](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771345(WS.10).aspx). If you are not expanding roles, server core should be just fine.   Usually I don't worry too much about disk space in a vmware environment. In general the amount of IOPS used by a vmware environment generates a spindle count that usually exceeds the space required as these days usually the smallest san drive you can buy is 146GB.